# Minimal GCC C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation

I'm trying to minimize the resources required to compile and run c++ code with GCC. I downloaded DevC++'s portable version but I'm looking more towards what files do I need to ONLY run gcc via command prompt and compile against all standard libraries. I'm not interested in Windows applications, only command prompt.

Is there an already stripped version of GCC out there? And if not, would anyone be able to lend me a hand

*I know of CygWin, and MinGW already, I'm looking for the bare minimals to using the cpp compiler for GCC. Like Tiny C where the entire functioning compiler and libraries is under 200 kilobytes, I'm looking to emulate that workflow with a cpp compiler.

Comment: another one to look at is cygwin

Comment: @Nerdtron: but notice that CygWin is not "just a compiler", it's an emulation layer for POSIX on Windows that happens to bundle also g++ (which produce executables that depend on CygWin dlls, while instead executables generated by MinGW are completely native).

Comment: From my experience, MinGW 3.4.5 executables were completely stand-alone. MinGW 4.5.2 executables seem to depend on a couple of DLLs that come with MinGW. Can't speak for any versions in between.

Comment: @MatteoItalia you can compile code with cygwin that doesn't depend on their libraries,  its a compiler switch.  I had to do that on a project awhile back.  Note that MinGW is available as a package you can install when setting up cygwin.  Executables created with cygwin are also completely native.  There's no emulation engine running, the code is native.

Comment: @Nerdtron: I'm quite sure that the switch you used tells to g++ to statically link the code included in cygwin1.dll. The code *is* native, but there's a POSIX compatibility layer (more or less as Wine is for Windows on Linux). Again, IIRC.

Comment: @MatteoItalia the code you're linking with is just a runtime library just like you'd link with MSVCRT using Visual C++ and IIRC is not any more of an 'emulation layer' than you have with MinGW.  The compiler switch I was using was because without it, it links to the default cygwin runtime library which is GPL and some would argue that this then requires your code to be GPL; As I recall you can use that switch, compile with cygwin and then not be dependent (statically or dynamically) on their runtime library and so not be encumbered by their license restrictions.

Comment: @Nerdtron: uh ok, good to know!

Answer (score 3):

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

> MinGW, a contraction of "Minimalist GNU for Windows", is a minimalist development environment for native Microsoft Windows applications.
>
> Primarily intended for use by developers working on the native MS-Windows platform, [...] MinGW includes:
>
> - A port of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC), including C, C++, ADA and Fortran compilers;
> - GNU Binutils for Windows (assembler, linker, archive manager)
> - A graphical and a command-line installer for MinGW and MSYS deployment on MS-Windows